# Extracting path in A* search

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to implement A* search with the following code:

```
void Map::findPath(Robot robot, Model target, vector<Node> nodeList) {
Node targetNode = target.getCurrentNode();
Node startNode = robot.getCurrentNode();

vector<Node> openList;
vector<Node> closedList;
openList.push_back(startNode);
while (!openList.empty()) {
    Node curNode = nodeWithLowestFScore(openList);
    if (curNode.equal(targetNode)) {
        /*cout << "WTF" << endl;
         Node *p = curNode.getParent();
         int i = 0;
         while (!p->equal(startNode)) {
         cout << p->getX() << " " << p->getY() << endl;
         p = p->getParent();
         cout << i++ << endl;
         }*/

        break;
    }

    closedList.push_back(curNode);
    removeFromVector(openList, curNode);
    vector<Node> adjNodes;
    curNode.getWalkableAdjacentNodes(nodeList, adjNodes);
    for (int i = 0; i < adjNodes.size(); i++) {
        if (inVector(closedList, adjNodes[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!inVector(closedList, adjNodes[i])) {
            adjNodes[i].setParent(&curNode);
            cout << "Child: " <<adjNodes[i].getX() << " " << adjNodes[i].getY() << endl;
            cout << "Parent: " << adjNodes[i].getParent()->getX()
                    << " " << adjNodes[i].getParent()->getY() << endl;
            adjNodes[i].setG(curNode.getG() + 1);
            adjNodes[i].setH(adjNodes[i].getDistance(targetNode, 'm'));
            adjNodes[i].setF();
            openList.push_back(adjNodes[i]);
        }
        if (inVector(closedList, adjNodes[i])) {
            if (curNode.getG() + 1 < adjNodes[i].getG()) {
                adjNodes[i].setParent(&curNode);
                adjNodes[i].setG(curNode.getG() + 1);
                adjNodes[i].setF();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here's the console output of this code(StartP = [x:-7, y:6], EndP = [x:0, y:-2]:

> 1. Child: -1 -2
> 2. Parent: 0 -2
> 3. Child: 1 -2
> 4. Parent: 0 -2
> 5. Child: -2 -2
> 6. Parent: -1 -2
> 7. Child: -1 -3
> 8. Parent: -1 -2
> 9. Child: -3 -2
> 10. Parent: -2 -2
> 11. Child: -3 -1
> 12. Parent: -3 -2
> 13. Child: -3 0
> 14. Parent: -3 -1
> 15. Child: -3 1
> 16. Parent: -3 0
> 17. Child: -4 0
> 18. Parent: -3 0
> 19. Child: -5 0
> 20. Parent: -4 0
> 21. Child: -5 1
> 22. Parent: -5 0
> 23. Child: -5 -1
> 24. Parent: -5 0
> 25. Child: -5 2
> 26. Parent: -5 1
> 27. Child: -5 3
> 28. Parent: -5 2
> 29. Child: -5 4
> 30. Parent: -5 3
> 31. Child: -5 5
> 32. Parent: -5 4
> 33. Child: -6 4
> 34. Parent: -5 4
> 35. Child: -4 4
> 36. Parent: -5 4
> 37. Child: -7 4
> 38. Parent: -6 4
> 39. Child: -8 4
> 40. Parent: -7 4
> 41. Child: -5 6
> 42. Parent: -5 5
> 43. Child: -5 7
> 44. Parent: -5 6
> 45. Child: -4 6
> 46. Parent: -5 6
> 47. Child: -3 2
> 48. Parent: -3 1
> 49. Child: -3 3
> 50. Parent: -3 2
> 51. Child: -2 2
> 52. Parent: -3 2
> 53. Child: -3 4
> 54. Parent: -3 3
> 55. Child: -4 4
> 56. Parent: -3 4
> 57. Child: -2 4
> 58. Parent: -3 4
> 59. Child: -1 4
> 60. Parent: -2 4
> 61. Child: -1 2
> 62. Parent: -2 2
> 63. Child: -3 6
> 64. Parent: -4 6
> 65. Child: -5 8
> 66. Parent: -5 7
> 67. Child: -9 4
> 68. Parent: -8 4
> 69. Child: -5 -2
> 70. Parent: -5 -1
> 71. Child: -1 -4
> 72. Parent: -1 -3
> 73. Child: 2 -2
> 74. Parent: 1 -2
> 75. Child: 3 -2
> 76. Parent: 2 -2
> 77. Child: 2 -3
> 78. Parent: 2 -2
> 79. Child: -2 -4
> 80. Parent: -1 -4
> 81. Child: -3 -4
> 82. Parent: -2 -4
> 83. Child: -3 -5
> 84. Parent: -3 -4
> 85. Child: -5 -3
> 86. Parent: -5 -2
> 87. Child: -9 5
> 88. Parent: -9 4
> 89. Child: -9 6
> 90. Parent: -9 5
> 91. Child: -8 6
> 92. Parent: -9 6
> 93. Child: -7 6
> 94. Parent: -8 6

It's a bit messy but I followed it. It reaches the starting point. (-7, 6)-> (-8, 6) -> (-9, 6) ... (-1, -2)->(0, -2).

However, if I uncomment the line that starts with "WTF" and want to back trace it it just gets into an infinite loop that prints (-7, 6) which is my EndP.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your actual problem and what you want us to fix?

Comment: Okay. I can backtrace from endP to startP by checking at the output. However I cant seem to print this out to console.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what's wrong given the code supplied. Here are some guesses: 1) The code to generate children also can generate the existing node which sets parent to itself in that case. 2) Your `equal` function is wrong, or 3) the code `while (!p->equal(startNode))` should be `while (p != NULL)` so long as parent pointers are default-initialized as `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay problematic line was this:  `adjNodes[i].setParent(&curNode);` I just had to reallocate a new Node, copy the contents of curNode to it and set that one as parent. Algorithm was fine.